# ovh vps windows install without vkm

Tags: windows, qemu

I have a problem after installing windows server 2022 using qemu, everything works until I restart the server to normal mode. Windows loads but it always gets an error at some point when loading windows.

command: qemu-system-x86_64 -machine pc -net nic -net user,hostfwd=tcp::3389-:3389 -m 2048M -enable-kvm -vga std -cdrom /mnt/iso.iso -drive file=/dev/sdb,format=raw,media=disk -boot once=d -vnc :1

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please read [ask] a good question?